# Sequence of numbers until the input is 0 (zero)

Tags: c++, console

I've no idea how to make the following.
I would like to enter a sequence of numbers and when I enter 0, to stop the cin (like I clicked Enter) and automatically cout only those numbers who (number%2==0) on another line. Is it posible to be done with function?
I hope you understood me :)

For example I'm entering 123456785435430 (I've entered '0', so the cin stop immideately and cout me 2 4 6 8 4 4 3)

Comment: I've just never done a program that do anything before hitting enter, so I've actually don't have any idea how to make it work :(

Comment: Hint: Use `cin.get()` to read every keystroke individually instead of waiting for `Enter`.

Comment: You don't have to know how to make it work, what have you tried? Show us an attempt so we can lead you in the right direction instead of writing the code for you and you learning nothing.

Comment: "Before hitting enter?" Aren't they going to hit enter after each number? Hence the need for 0.

Comment: No, this is the difficulty of the situation for me :). us2012, what can I enter in cin.get(?). Can I make a variable int a for ex. and do the following. while(1) { if(cin.get(a)==0) break; }; ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to be done with function.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, no it's **not**. `std::istream::get` [only accept chars](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).

Comment: 3 mod 2 is **NOT** 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need something along the lines of this:

```
char x;
std::vector<int> evens;
do {
    std::cin.get(x);
    int v = x - '0'; // int value
    if (v % 2 == 0 and v != 0)
        evens.push_back(v);
} while (x != '0');

for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = evens.begin(); it != evens.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << (*it) << " ";
```

---

Here's the version for your exercise:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void brc() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    if (x == 0) return;
    if (x % 2 == 0)
        std::cout << x << " ";
    brc();
}

int main() {
    brc();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: More like x = std::cin.get()'"'";„”„”'

Comment: Wow, guys thank you. But can't it be made simpler because I really can't understand anything :(. I study C++ at school, but this seems to be on Advanced Level. The last thing we've learnt were the functions. I'm sorry if I look like a cheeky.

Comment: @user2171820, what's the prototype of the function you need?

Comment: well we've lastly learnt & and *, It should be in a function that I will be able to call in the main() { here };

Comment: Write a program named 'progr.cpp', in which Enter with Standart Entrance sequence of numbers until entering of zero (0), after the entering of zero, output in an intervals on a same line all the numbers in the sequence that are with an even number of digits. Use function brc();

Comment: @user2171820, if it helped could you please at least accept this as an answer?

Comment: Well, I'm using xCode on Mac, and it isn't working. I'm cin-ing 1 time. When I enter the first 0, nothing happens.

Comment: @user2171820, well, nothing should happen. The `0` is discarded and nothing is printed. Remember that you have to submit the list of numbers separated by a space. Try inputting `1 2 3 5 6 6 8` and press enter: you should see `2 6 6 8` appear on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple version that works with a given delimiter,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string input_until_delimiter (char delimiter)
{

    string buffer = new string ();

    char c = delimiter;

    while ((c = get()) != delimiter) buffer += c;

    return buffer;

}
```